# Enabling C++ constructor subject to say std::is_floating_point<T>

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, template-meta-programming, enable-if

I'm trying to enable a default constructor only if the class's template
parameter is floating point. Note `T` is not a parameter type nor return type
but the class template type.

```
template <typename T>
  struct Thing
{
    const T x;
    Thing( T t) : x(t) {}
    //only turn on this constructor if T is floating point
    Thing() : x(std::numeric_limits<T>::quiet_NaN()) {}
};

//...

Thing<double> dt;
Thing<float> ft;
Thing<int> it1;
Thing<int> it2(3);
```

I tried putting the following in front of the constructor

```
template <std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, bool> = true>
```

And I tried putting the `std::enable_if_t...= true` stuff as an argument to the
default constructor (and various other attempts).

Both of these tries rightfully complains about `it1` so that's good, but when I remove that, they both also complain about `it2`! I don't understand and can't find the magic incantation.

Thanks for any insights.

I forgot to mention, I'm stuck on C++17.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+constructor+SFINAE  Not all are duplicates, but many are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `requires`:

```
Thing() requires std::is_floating_point_v<T>
    : x(std::numeric_limits<T>::quiet_NaN())
{}
```

---

Or, in C++17:

```
template <typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<U>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
Thing()
    : x(std::numeric_limits<T>::quiet_NaN())
{}
```

The SFINAE condition must depend on a template parameter of the function itself. Otherwise it can be checked when the class is first instantiated, even if the function isn't used.

I also tweaked a few things, purely for style.

Comment: Are you sure it picks the right one: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/arc43fxab? Somehow, the CDTA as well as giving the template para explictly, fails here.

Comment: Nice and clean, but I forgot to mention that I'm stuck on C++17. (I've edited my question to say that.)

Comment: @Mustang Added C++17 version.